# Read emails from IMAP + Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, email, laravel, imap, laravel-5.1

I'm looking for a solution to do the following:

I want to read emails from an **IMAP mailbox**, show them in a **table** and give each of them a **ticket number**. They are also collected in **categories** (this is done by keywords in the subject of the mail). They also get a **status** (
in treatment, open, finished).

I was wondering if any of you had experience with **reading emails from IMAP in Laravel 5.1**. What's the best solution for this? I've found the [barbushin/php-imap](https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap) library and the [ddeboer/imap](https://github.com/ddeboer/imap) library. But which one is better or with wich ones did you have a good experience?

Or another option? I just want to make it best practice and easy to write.

Comment: Questions asking which of two things is better, are off-topic here because they result in answers based on opinions. Just see which one fits your needs better, try to implement the solution and come back with questions if you encounter problems.

Answer (score 0):

I find a laravel package for imap connection.

May be is useful for you:
http://packalyst.com/packages/package/zalazdi/laravel-imap